# javascript split variable on every 3 characters but if there is 8 characters to still show all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a requirement in which I thought that I had satisfied it with

"normal" javascript variable that I get

```
var myString = "263290004";
var str = "" + data[0].locatn_k;
var arr = str.match(/.{3}/g); // => ['329', '193', '914']
var str2 = arr.join('-'); // => '329-193-914'
```

Result:

```
263-290-004
```

**HOWEVER**

```
18311009
```

Becomes..

```
183-110
```

WHEN I WANT

```
183-110-09
```

Comment: You question code is broken, you have variables that you never used.

Comment: I'm sorry about that , I was in the middle of making my question from my code and jsfiddle,  but your answer is correct , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var arr = str.match(/.{1,3}/g);
```

<sub>Results:</sub>

```
console.log( arr.join('-') );
// "8"         >> "8"
// "04564"     >> "045-64"
// "8213221"   >> "821-322-1"
// "263290004" >> "263-290-004"
```

> **/.{1,3}/g**
>   **.{1,3}** matches any character (except newline)
>   Quantifier: **{1,3}** Between **1** and **3** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>   **g** modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)